# Override main method

Tags: java

Can we override the method as mentioned below:-

"`public static void main`"

Comment: Can you give an example of when you would want to do this, and why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. `main` is a static method, and is thus not polymorphic. You may *hide* it be defining another static `main` method in a subclass, though.

Answer (score 6):

No and you are losing the focus here. The main method has a single purpose and is declared logically for that sole purpose:

The main method in Java belongs to a class but not to an Object. Objects are created at The `main()` in Java is the start point in your application, there is no way to start your application from an instance specific method. That is why the static keyword make perfect sense with the main method. In fact all the parts of the main method declaration make perfect sense when you think like the 'jvm' and picture what the main method does (starts the application):

- `public`, because this method must be accessible by the jvm (not written by you).
- `static`, implying this method can be accessed without having an object (because it's representation never changes), but here the logic is easy understood if you think like the jvm again; "I don't have any objects to create (instantiate) objects, so I need a static method to start the application as there simple isn't any logical way to get an instance specific method up yet as I don't have anything up yet to create objects".
- `void` This method can't logically return anything because there is nothing up yet to return anything to. It is the start point of the application.
  main I am the main method as without me you won't have an application.
- `String[] args` Send me data you may feel useful for my startup.

Answer (score 3):

We can not override the static method because static metod is a class method and the scope of this method within the same class itself. So if you want to override forcefully then you have to define it outside of that class scope which does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't override a static method.

It wouldn't really make sense to anyway. Since you don't need an instance of the class, you don't need polymorphic behavior. You would just change the all from `SomeParent.main()` to `SomeChild.main()`

Answer (score 0):

MAIN is a class method (since its `static` by definition). Hence, it does not makes sense to "override" it (or for that matter any static method).

The concept of "overriding" is only for instance methods.

[This](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/OverridingVsHiding) is a good read with regards to the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to override static methods, since they are not instance level methods, but class level methods.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this, don't know if its correct way to override method, but I am able to override main method like this,

```
class MainOverride {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainOverridden mo = new MainOverridden();

        String [] s = {"a","b"};
        mo.main(s);


    }

}

class MainOverridden extends MainOverride {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Main overridden");

    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot override a static method. You have just hide the main method `MainOverride` class.

Comment: He hasn't even hidden it. It's still possible to run `MainOverride` as an application, just as it was before. The fact it has a subclass is irrelevant if you're not telling it to run that subclass.

Comment: Thank you for comments, i got from it that the way i have followed for overriding is not practically valid, but please can you celebrate more - as i am new to java :)